# How to restrict the user to input only one digit after decimal point in html text field

Tags: html

I have tried the following to restrict the user to input only numbers by

```
<input type="text"  onkeypress="return event.charCode &gt; 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode &lt; 57"/>
```

but how can I allow only one digit after a decimal point like 0.5, 1.0, 2, 2.5 etc and not 0.56, 1.22 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jquery(since I don't see jquery tagged in your question) then you can do it like this

```js
$(function () {
 
    $('#number').bind('paste', function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!/^\d*(\.\d{1,2})+$/.test($(self).val())) $(self).val('');
        }, 0);
    });
    
    $('.decimal').keypress(function (e) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
        var newValue = this.value + character;
        if (isNaN(newValue) || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 2)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
        var pointIndex = value.indexOf('.');
        return  pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
    }
});
```

```css
.decimal {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="number" class="decimal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a pattern (HTML5): **`...type="number" name="..." pattern="([0-9]{1,2}).([0-9]{1})" title="...`**. A pattern specifies a regular expression to check the input value against.

Answer (score 1):

You can use step attribute to specify the legal number intervals for your  element.

```
<input type="number" step="0.1">
```

if you set step to 0.1 only decimal numbers with 1 digit after decimal point will be valid.